# Express.js PUT and DELETE methods not working

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, put, http-delete

I am trying to create a simple to-do app using Node, Express, and sqlite3. I have GET and POST methods that work perfectly, but my PUT and DELETE are not accessed, instead, I'm being met with a 404 status and `CANNOT DELETE/PUT \todos`.

I am not using any HTML forms for the requests, everything is done on the backend and I use Thunder doe the requests.

I have a `database.js` which creates the database and this is the `app.js` with all the endpoints:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const db = require('./database.js');

let port = 3000 || 5000;

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({Page: 'Main page'});
});

app.get('/todos', (req, res) => {
    db.all(`SELECT * FROM todo`, (err, rows) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).json({err: err.message});
        res.json(rows);
    });
});

app.post('/todos', (req, res) => {
    const {task} = req.body; 
    console.log(req.body);
    if(!task) return res.status(400).json({error: 'Task not specified.'});

    db.run(`INSERT INTO todo (task) VALUES (?)`, [task], function(err){
        if(err) return res.status(500).json({err: err.message});

        res.json({id: this.lastID, task: task, completed: false});
    });
});

app.put('/todos/:id', function(req, res) {
    const {id} = req.params;
    db.run(`UPDATE todo SET completed = 1 WHERE id = ?`, [id], function(err){
        if(err) return res.status(500).json({err: err.message});
        console.log(id);
        if(this.changes === 0) return res.status(404).json({err: 'Task not found.'});
        
        res.json({ message: 'Todo marked as completed.'});
    });
});


app.delete('/todos/:id', function(req, res){
    const {id} = req.params;
    console.log(id);
    db.run(`DELETE FROM todo WHERE id = ?`, [id], function(err){
        if(err) return res.status(500).json({err: err.message});
        console.log(id);
        if(this.changes === 0) return res.status(404).json({err: 'Task not found.'});

        res.json({ message: 'Todo successfully deleted.'});
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on the port ${port}`);
});`
```

I am using Thunder on VSCode to make the requests, and this is the response for the PUT and DELETE methods, with a status `404 Not Found`.

The requests:

`DELETE`: `http://localhost:3000/todos/?id=2`

`PUT`: `http://localhost:3000/todos/?id=2`

And a sample response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>Cannot DELETE /todos</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add the request you are sending. It is difficult to know why it responds that without knowing what the sent request was.

Comment: @Brettski I have edited to add the requests

Comment: Pretty sure it should be `http://localhost:3000/todos/2`  to match '/todos/:id'

Answer (score 0):

To match the route of `'/todos/:id'` you should use `http://localhost:3000/todos/2` not `http://localhost:3000/todos/?id=2`.

Using `http://localhost:3000/todos/?id=2` you would get the id from the query string. (plus it doesn't match the route signature provided.)

Comment: Thank you! I tried it out now and it indeed that. I still am not clear on how to define the path and query parameters appropriately.

Comment: Also changing the route to `/todos/` and then getting the id as a query with `{id} = req.query` worked too